# What does Microsoft host for add-ins published to the Office Add-in store?

Tags: office-js, office-store

I am having problems finding details about publishing an Add-in to the office store. I have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store) but it does not provide details on how the publishing works.
Does the store just store a catalog for the manifests? Or does it host the html, js and other files too?

Comment: That is correct. Add-ins are Web Apps that you host, the Store/Appsource is only a catalog of manifest files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource you have found is correct one and describes step by step submission process. You also right that the Office store is the catalog of the manifest files, which pointed to web applications. You have several options how to publish your application described in [Deploy and publish your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish). To have better picture on the topic you may read the following document: [Components of an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#components-of-an-office-add-in). The picture below should be the answer on your question ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for confirming this with me! Does this mean the review process done by Microsoft before adding your product to the store is just a black box test?
Wouldn't this allow the host to change the app at any time after it has been published to the store? (Potentially adding bugs not found during the review)

Comment: @braewalker Ha, "black box" check. Sure you may call it like this, but they will test your product on different platforms as well as functionality. Yes, you are in control of your web application part and able to update it at any time, but you shouldn't do this. What's wrong to increase version of your app and go through submission process again? There is benefit for you as one more iteration of QA, isn't it? Anyways you understood everything correctly.

Comment: Yes, i agree with what you are saying about going through another iteration. I just assumed they would want to see more in depth, and have more control with the applications that are being uploaded to their store.

Comment: The XML manifest is digitally signed by Microsoft, and includes some permission-based attributes - so yes, while you can change your app (usually to *fix* bugs, not add them of course) you are limited to changes the original XML allows.